# Issues with placementTransform Matrix when loading multiple models to Autodesk Forge

Tags: three.js, translation, autodesk-forge

When loading multiple models, I am using the placementTransform parameters.
the issues I am facing is that the Rotation works however the translation does not.

```
var Rmat = new THREE.Matrix4();
Tmat=new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(X,Y,Z);
Rmat.makeRotationZ(Angle);
Rmat.multiply(Tmat);

var modelOptions = {
        placementTransform: Rmat,
        sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getRoot().getPropertyDbManifest()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `placementTransform` should support both translation and rotation. Try applying the transformations individually (only translation or only rotation), see if both are applied as expected. And also double-check if you're multiplying the matrices in the correct order.

Moreover, if you can reproduce the issue in a sample app, please share it with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` and we'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the combinations the only one that worked was using the globalOffset
and commented this._firstGlobalOffset the code that worked is as follows:

```
//this._firstGlobalOffset = {x:0,y:0,z:0}; // Commented

var Rmat = new THREE.Matrix4();
Rmat.makeRotationZ(Angle);


var modelOptions = {
        placementTransform: Rmat,
        globalOffset:{x:X,y:X,z:Z},
        sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getRoot().getPropertyDbManifest()
    };
```